# Find replace MS Word with Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have written a macro that replaces a file path with the current files location in Word 2016.

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim s As String
s = ActiveDocument.Path
Dim sa As String
sa = Replace(s + "\test1.xlxs", "\", "\\")

For Each myStoryRange In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    With myStoryRange.Find
        .Text = "C:*test1.xlsx"
        .Replacement.Text = sa
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Next myStoryRange


End Sub
```

This shows the error "the replacement text contains a group number that is out of range"

The 'sa' variable has the correct string in it, i checked this at run time.
Also when i replace

```
.Replacement.Text = sa
```

with

```
.Replacement.Text = "bla"
```

It works.
At run time an example of 'sa' would be "C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\test1.xlsx"

Does anyone have any suggestions what might be the problem?

Comment: Are you replacing a single backslash with a double one? The syntax is  `Replace( expression,find,replace...`)

Comment: Not sure if related, but backslashes and wildcards don't work well together. See [here](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/35339-replace-text-contains-group-number-out-range.html)

Comment: it is a bit more complicated than that.
I replace all instances of "C:*test1.xlsx" with a constructed string which itself is derived from the location that the current file rests in and the replacement of the single slash with the double slash is so that it can be used properly later on.

Comment: It's unclear why you need a double slash when a normal file path uses one.

Comment: the string is then used in a link which requires one slash as an escape character and the other one for the file path.
That said your suggestion with the wildcards and backslashes worked.
replacing the '\' with '^92^92' was the answer.
Thank you
If you put it as the answer i will mark it answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcards and backslashes do not work well together when finding and replacing text - the backslash has its own particular use.

To replace a backslash in this case, use its ASCII equivalent: `"^92^92"` instead of `"\\"`.

Comment: Brilliant Thank you.